# How to use width and fill option without using it in every bracket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am novice learning Python, would appreciate for little help.

As you can see I created two letters `Z` and `L` and used `width` and `fill` command on each line.

So, I would like to use `width` and `fill` command on letter `H` on all lines together and not by typing it to each one.

Can you help me to make it a function?

Code:

```
import tkinter

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=600)
canvas.pack()

## Z
canvas.create_line(50, 50, 220, 50, 50, 220, 220, 220, width=5, fill="red")

## L
canvas.create_line(230, 50, 230, 220, 390, 220, width=5, fill="green")

## H
canvas.create_line(410, 50, 410, 220)
canvas.create_line(410, 125, 560, 125)
canvas.create_line(560, 50, 560, 220)
```

I basically want to write it something like this:

```
B(width=5, fill="blue")

B = canvas.create_line(410, 50, 410, 220)
B = canvas.create_line(410, 125, 560, 125)
B = canvas.create_line(560, 50, 560, 220)
```

And Not Like this:

```
canvas.create_line(410, 50, 410, 220, width=5, fill="blue")
canvas.create_line(410, 125, 560, 125, width=5, fill="blue")
canvas.create_line(560, 50, 560, 220, width=5, fill="blue")
```

I know it is bad but I hope you get my point.

Comment: which library is this? I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: @Boris Sorry, I add it to the code.

Comment: Do you know how to write functions? What have you tried? Create a function, pass in the canvas, and have it call `create_line` with any options you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to define your own function that accepted a variable number of coordinate `tuples` and made multiple calls to `create_line()` for each one that was passed to it when it's called.

The code below shows what I mean (I commented out your code so you can compare it more easily to what you had).

```
import tkinter as tk

def draw_lines(canvas, width, fill, *lines):
    """ Draw multiple lines on the same canvas, with the same width,
        and fill.
    """
    for line in lines:
        canvas.create_line(*line, width=width, fill=fill)


canvas = tk.Canvas(width=1000, height=600)
canvas.pack()

## Z
draw_lines(canvas, 5, "red",
           (50, 50, 220, 50),
           (50, 220, 220, 220))
#canvas.create_line(50, 50, 220, 50, 50, 220, 220, 220, width=5, fill="red")

## L
draw_lines(canvas, 5, "green", (230, 50, 230, 220, 390, 220))
#canvas.create_line(230, 50, 230, 220, 390, 220, width=5, fill="green")

## H
draw_lines(canvas, 5, "green",
           (410, 50, 410, 220),
           (410, 125, 560, 125),
           (560, 50, 560, 220))

#B(width=5, fill="blue")
#
#B = canvas.create_line(410, 50, 410, 220)
#B = canvas.create_line(410, 125, 560, 125)
#B = canvas.create_line(560, 50, 560, 220)

tk.mainloop()
```